# Get the href value and then find it as an id

Tags: jquery, anchor

I'm trying to build this section based on anchor navigation. When I click on a link I get to the desired anchor and the clicked link gains a class with a specific style, so far it works well:

**HTML**

```
<body>

  <nav>
    <div class="anchor-link" > <a href="#anchor1" > Anchor 1 </a> </div>
    <div class="anchor-link"> <a href="#anchor2"> Anchor 2 </a> </div>
    <div class="anchor-link"> <a href="#anchor3"> Anchor 3 </a> </div>
    <div class="anchor-link"> <a href="#anchor4"> Anchor 4 </a> </div>
    <div class="anchor-link"> <a href="#anchor5"> Anchor 5 </a> </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="main-wrap">
    <div id="anchor1"></div>
    <div id="anchor2"></div>
    <div id="anchor3"></div>
    <div id="anchor4"></div>
    <div id="anchor5"></div>
   </div>

</body>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".anchor-link").on("click", function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
```

Now I'd like to get the value inside the href but this does not work and it returns undefined:

```
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      console.log(href);
   })
```

Assuming it worked, and the var href holds the value of the clicked link, for example "#anchor1", how would I have to proceed to then find in the "main-wrap", the div with the id of "#anchor1"?

Would this work, and how would I have to fill that find query?

```
$(".main-wrap").find(...);
```

Comment: For correctly getting the href: use this instead: `var href = $("a", this).attr('href');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a jsFiddle doing what you want: [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rkjs4y62/1/)

And there is the jquery snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".anchor-link").on("click", function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
      var href = $("a", this).attr('href');
      $(href).html("You clicked " + href + " !");
   });
});
```

You where trying to get the href of the `$(this)` element refering to the `<div class="anchor-link" >` clicked, wich does not have any `href` attribute.

By doing this: `$("a", this).attr('href')` you tell *Take the value of the href attribute of the `<a>` element in the div I just clicked*

After this you can select the corresponding div with `$(href)`

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to get `href` of a `<div>` and it does not have that attribute

Change selector to the `<a>` or look inside the div using find()

```
$(".anchor-link").on("click", function(){
   var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  ....

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following click handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".anchor-link a").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parents('.anchor-link').addClass("active");
    $(this).parents('.anchor-link').siblings().removeClass("active");
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      console.log(href);
   });
})
```